# What is known about the complexity of Network Diversion?

Tags: ds.algorithms, graph-theory, graph-algorithms, parameterized-complexity

In the **Network Diversion** problem, we are given an *undirected* graph $G$ on $n$ vertices, with specified nodes $s$ and $t$ and specified edge $e$, and a positive integer $k$, and are tasked with determining if it is possible to delete at most $k$ edges from $G$ to produce a graph which

1. contains an $st$-path, and
2. has the property that every $st$-path in $G$ passes through the edge $e$.

In other words, we want to know if by removing a "small" number of edges from $G$, we can force anyone walking from $s$ to $t$ to go through a specific edge $e$.

**Question:** what is known about the (exact or parameterized) complexity of Network Diversion? Is this problem known to be polynomial-time solvable, NP-hard, W[1]-hard, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a recent preprint where we show it's polynomial-time on planar graphs: https://arxiv.org/abs/2305.01314. In general graphs, it remains open whether it is polynomial-time or NP-complete.

An FPT algorithm for general graphs can be given by using *flow-augmentation*: https://arxiv.org/abs/2111.03450